# What does "has got to be" mean?

Tags: meaning

Source of the phrase:

> Player Union Strikes Called Off
>   "And looking along the table, really, there should be more smiles than you're seeing. I think people are tired. The reason there should be more smiles is, quite simply, there will be no strike. And that **has got to be** for the good of the game, for the good of everybody"--a quotation from Richard Scudamore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synonymous with "has to be" or "must be"

Comment: +1 In each of the cases (*has got to be; has to be;* or *must be*), the expression represents a conclusion of an analysis, not an imperative.